Docker build . hangs indefinitely without feedback on MacOS Big Sur
I'm new to Docker, and following along a course. I went step by step creating some basic files to start a Django project on Docker, which are the following:

My DockFile is this one:
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="user"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -n venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user

Then, my .dockerignore file is this:
# Git
.git 
.gitignore

# Docker
.docker

#Python
app/__pycache__/
app/*/__pycache__/
app/*/*/__pycache__/
app/*/*/*/__pycache__/
.env/
.venv/
venv/

Finally, the requirements reads:
Django>=3.2.4,<3.3
djangorestframework>=3.12.4,<3.13

After that I'm supposed to run docker build ., but when I do it hangs and does nothing.

I had to shut it down a couple of times. Any idea of what I am doing wrong or at least have some feedback?
